# Getting EmptyFileException despite passsing non-empty input stream to WorkbookFactory

Tags: java, apache-poi, runtime-error

The code below is returning an EmptyFileException, despite the fact that the file is not empty(as can be seen in the output):

```
public class RecordImpl {

    private AssociateImpl associate;

    public AssociateImpl getAssociate() {
        return associate;
    }

    public void setAssociate(AssociateImpl associate) {
        this.associate = associate;
    }


    public Document createInsertRecord()throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        String msg = "";
        InputStream inputStream = associate.getFileInputStream();
        byte[] binaryRep = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        System.out.println("File length: "+binaryRep.length);
        String year = getYear(inputStream, associate.getPosition());

        Document newRecord = new Document();

        /*remaining code*/

        return newRecord;
    }


    public String getYear(InputStream inputStream, String position)throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        System.out.println("Inside RecordImpl: getYear()");
        //code throws error at the line below
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(associate.getFileInputStream()); 
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(position);

        DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        String year = "";

        /*remaining code*/

        return year;
    }

}
```

The length of the byte array is shown to be 21787, showing that the input stream is not empty. And yet the empty file error gets thrown. The output, with the stack trace is shown below:

```
File length: 21787
Oct 15, 2018 12:11:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/my-goals] threw exception [org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)] with root cause
org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.peekFirstNBytes(IOUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.peekFirst8Bytes(IOUtils.java:57)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:135)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:177)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:149)
    at com.cerner.model.impl.RecordImpl.getYear(RecordImpl.java:64)
    at com.cerner.model.impl.RecordImpl.createInsertRecord(RecordImpl.java:42)
    at com.cerner.model.impl.ActionImpl.insertNewRecord(ActionImpl.java:71)
    at com.cerner.model.impl.ActionImpl.performAction(ActionImpl.java:43)
    at com.cerner.my_goals.GoalResource.uploadFile(GoalResource.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The file being passed is definitely a non-empty XLSX file. Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

I think with your call:

```
byte[] binaryRep = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

the `inputStream` will move to the end of the stream, so that the remaining bytes are `0`.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the issue, thanks. But if i call the getYear() method before storing the input stream into the byte array, I get a "stream already closed error". Also, mark() and reset() don't work for InputStream. Is there a way to get around this, like resetting pointer to 0 some other way?

Comment: Just create a new input streamto the file and use the new one, Maybe wrapo the first `inputStream` in a `using` block